# How to Read myFolder txt File in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to Read textFile in my Userfolder in UWP but i got error like this

'Access to the path 'C:\Users\Administrator\log\config.txt' is denied.'

```
 string path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\log\config.txt";
 string textValue = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
 Debug.WriteLine(textValue);
```

UWP can't read folder in a specific path???

Comment: are you log in with an administrator account to your window?

Comment: Hey. You should read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Answer (score 4):

UWP was designed as a sandbox to increase a user security. Thus, by default your app can see only limited list of folders, like its private subfolder or any of standard locations like My Docs, My Pictures etc. If you need something outside the default, there is a manifest permission to be specified (broadFileSystemAccess) or then let the user pick deisred file interactively to get explicit consent:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

> In most cases, to get access to file system locations, your app can
> use the FileOpenPicker, FileSavePicker, FolderPicker, and
> FutureAccessList APIs. If you want to request approval to use the
> broadFileSystemAccess capability, then you must provide specific
> reasons as to why those APIs aren't sufficient for your needs.